# Can lagrange multipliers be vectors?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

In [this thread about the derivation of lagrange multipliers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23972/1258964) as well as [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Summary_and_rationale) the Lagrangian is defined as

$ F(\vec{x}, \vec{\lambda}) = f(\vec{x}) - \langle \vec{\lambda}, \vec{g(x)} \rangle $.

I thought that $\lambda$ had to be a scalar in order to constrain $ \nabla g $ and $ \nabla f $ to be collinear.

How can I interpret the formulation in which $\lambda$ is a vector?

Comment: Well, if you have a handful of constraints, you have a handful of scalars as Lagrange multipliers instead of just one -- or a vector from $\mathbb R^{\text{handful}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to optimize a function $f$ subject to constrains $g_1=0,\ldots,g_k =0$, then the key point of the theory of Lagrange multipliers is that, at a (constrained) local extremum $x_0$, the gradient $\nabla(f)$ will be normal to the domain given by the constraints. When there are multiple constraints, this means that $\nabla(f)(x_0)$ will be a linear combination of the gradients $\nabla(g_1)(x_0),\ldots,\nabla(g_k)(x_0)$, that is, there will be $\vec{\lambda} \in \mathbb R^k$ such that

$$
\nabla(f)(x_0) = \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i \nabla(g_i)(x_0)
$$

which translates into a "Lagrangian"
$$
F(\vec{x},\vec{\lambda}) = f(\vec{x}) - \langle \vec{\lambda},\vec{g}(x)\rangle,
$$
where $\vec{g} = (g_1,\ldots,g_k)$. Thus the Lagrange multipliers form a vector in $\mathbb R^k$ where $k$ is given by the number of constraining functions (so in particular, while it is a vector, it is not a vector in the same space as the vector $\vec{x}$).

Comment: Thanks! Some clarifying logic I'd like to further confirm:
(1) The gradient of a function is orthogonal to the level curves of that function. (2) The single constraint condition $\nabla f(x) = \lambda \nabla g(x), g(x)=0$ enforces that $x$ meets the constraint and the gradient of $f$ is orthogonal to that constraint.
(3) Every constraint is effectively ANDed into a new constraint because we require $g_i(x) = 0 \forall i$.
(4) The summation of all $\lambda_i \nabla g_i(x)$ is the correct way to state the orthogonal complement of a $g(x)$ that contains multiple $g_i$.

Comment: (1) this is correct (and straight-forward to prove, once you sort out the definitions). For (2) you seem to have 2 conditions -- $g(x)=0$ and $\nabla f(x)-\lambda \nabla g(x)=0$. The first says $x$ satisfies the constraint and the second that the gradient of $f$ is orthogonal to the constraint. tbc...

Comment: For (3) the contraints are indeed "AND"ed in that we are taking the intersection of the sets that satisfy each constraint individually. The theory of Lagrange multipliers *assumes* that $k$ constraints are "generic" in that, near $x_0$, the $k$ gradient vectors are linearly independent, so that by the Implicit Function Theorem, the locus which satisfies all of the constraint conditions is smooth.