# Lagrange multipliers for functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, reference-request, lagrange-multiplier, entropy

I am attempting to prove that the multivariate distribution with maximum entropy for a given covariance is a Gaussian. (PRML, Bishop, problem 2.14).

Bishop suggests the use of Lagrange multipliers - concretely, that should maximize
$$
\text{H}[x] = -\int p(x)\log(x)dx
$$
subject to the constraints
\begin{align*}
\int p(x)\,dx &= 1\\
\int xp(x)\,dx &= \mu\\
\int p(x)(x - \mu)(x - \mu)^T\,dx &= \Sigma.
\end{align*}

Applying Lagrange multipliers to the maximization of a functional (as opposed to the maximization of a function on $\mathbb{R}^N$) is alien to me. If someone could direct me to a reference describing why Lagrange multipliers continue to "work" in infinite dimensional function spaces, I would appreciate it.

Comment: 7 months later, I found an answer - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279518/constrained-variational-problems-intuition/281284#281284

Comment: Better late than never - thanks!