# How do Lagrange multipliers work for functionals? (Motivation: the catenary)

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, classical-mechanics

I'm fairly new to the calculus of variations, so please bear with me. This question is very similar to [this other question posted six months ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3642328/lagrange-multipliers-for-functionals) that has as yet not received any answers. If a good discussion is had here I will be sure to send the  findings over to the previous asker. With that out of the way, here is my question:

I want to derive the equation of the catenary using the Euler-Lagrange equation. I know that this has been done many times, but I want to do it myself. Below is a diagram:

[image: catenary]

Let the path of the wire between the two points be described by some function $y$. It is natural to want to minimize the potential energy of the wire. Assuming the wire has a constant density $\rho$ this boils down to
$$U[y]=\rho g\int_{x_1}^{x_2}y~\mathrm{d}x$$
But of course, there are three constraints:
$$y(x_1)=y_1~;~y(x_2)=y_2$$
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\sqrt{1+{y'}^2}~\mathrm{d}x=L$$
The problem is I don't really know how to apply these constraints properly. I tried using the [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) but this only brought me to
$$\rho g(x_2-x_1)=0\implies x_1=x_2$$
Which is obviously nonsense. I looked at [Wikiversity's derivation of the catenary](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/PlanetPhysics/Equation_of_Catenary_Via_Calculus_of_Variations) and they mention using a Lagrange multiplier. But, the only context in which I'm familiar with using Lagrange multipliers in is when we want to extremize some function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ subject to some constraint $g(\mathbf{x})=C$. My main question is: **how do we use Lagrange multipliers for extremizing functionals?** And why do the same methods work as to extremizing *functions*?

Thanks for your time,

-K.defaoite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your formulation is that the integration along the solution curve should be

$$
\mathcal{L}=\rho g\int_{x_1}^{x_2}y \sqrt{1+y'^2}dx+\lambda\left(\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\sqrt{1+y'^2}dx-L\right)
$$

You are using in the first integral $dx$ instead of $ds$.

NOTE

The potential energy is given by

$$
\rho g \int_{x_1}^{x_2}y ds
$$

and the length is given by

$$
L = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}ds
$$

so the lagrangian is

$$
\mathcal{L}=\rho g\int_{x_1}^{x_2}y ds + \lambda\left(\int_{x_1}^{x_2}ds-L\right)
$$

or

$$
\mathcal{L}=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\left(\left(\rho g y+\lambda\right)\sqrt{1+y'^2}-\frac{\lambda L}{(x_2-x_1)}\right)dx
$$

because $ds = \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2} = \sqrt{1+y'^2}dx$

Comment: I'm a little confused. How did you reach this expression? Why is there an extra $y$ in the first integral but not the second? Also this doesn't quite get to my main problem - the usage of Lagrange multipliers for functionals. I appreciate the answer, but could you elaborate a little more on the details of the above? Thanks!

Comment: Please. See the attached note.

Comment: Oh, I see my error. Thanks so much.

Comment: Still, would you be able to point me to any good resources about optimization and constrained optimization for functionals? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: As an introductory book to the Calculus of Variations I can remember Gelfand and Fomin's Calculus of Variations. You can find it on the web http://users.uoa.gr/~pjioannou/mech2/READING/Gelfand_Fomin_Calculus_of_Variations.pdf

Comment: Cesareo, many thanks for the detailed answer and reference.